# Spring API Gateway - Path regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения, spring-cloud

Есть Spring API Gateway c следующей конфигурацией:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      default-filters:
        - RewritePath=/api/v1/.*?/(?<remaining>.*), /$\{remaining}
      routes:
        - predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/stories/**
          uri: lb://story
```

При запросе к `/api/v1/stories/` редирект происходит правильно, но если `/` в конце убрать `/api/v1/stories` то получается ошибка:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target
> resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Искал ответ [тут](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html), но исправить так и не удалось.

Контроллер в `story` сервисе выглядит так:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<ListDto<StoryDto>> list(@NotNull @RequestBody @Valid StoryFilterDto filter) {
    log.debug("Get Story list by filter: {}", filter);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(storyService.getList(filter));
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы от слеша в конце можно было избавиться, и отправлять запрос прямо на `/api/v1/stories`?

Comment: А если использовать `/api/v1/[^/]*(?:/(?<remaining>.*))?`  ?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew у меня не один микросервис остальное удалил для сокращения. Вы имеете в виду в `- Path` или `- RewritePath`?

Comment: `RewritePath` - у вас регекс только там.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżewтак так Gateway стартовать не хочет Refresh routes error